# C# version of PriorityQueue for compare

Tags: c#, priority-queue

I have the following code for Java and want to achieve same in C# .
please suggest

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pQ= new PriorityQueue<Integer>((x,y)->Integer.compare(y, x));
```

I did convert Integer to int but does not helps.

.NET version < 6

Comment: There is a [`PriorityQueue` class in .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: In C# you need to specify the type the priority queue holds and also what type the priority queue should use to prioritise things. In you're case simply `var pq = new PriorityQueue<int, int>();` should do the trick. See [my demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YQpIl). Note that the `PriorityQueue` class only exists in .NET 6 and newer

Comment: Unfortunately ..working on a lower version.. than 6

Comment: Will edit my question

Comment: @DotNetDev19 the source of .NET 6 is available on github. Just copy from [that source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs) and use that copy until you upgrade to .net 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on .NET framework 6 (or newer) you just need:

```
var pQ = new PriorityQueue<int, int>();
```

If you add items you can give them a priority(2nd parameter):

```
pQ.Enqueue(1, 100);
pQ.Enqueue(2, 10);
// ...
```

or you have a complex logic that you want to reuse, then use a custom comparer:

```
public class MyFancyIntComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        // replace following with a fancy logic
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

---

```
var pQ = new PriorityQueue<int, int>(new MyFancyIntComparer());
```

---

If you are on a lower version of the .NET framework you might use(copy&paste) these internal PriorityQueues: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=priorityqueue

Comment: thanks..but i have lower version

Comment: FYI/ FWIW .NET 6 is **not** a version of .NET Framework, it's .NET Core 5. For marketing reasons MS decided to rename .NET Core to simply .NET starting with .NET Core 4 which they released under the name .NET 5. Why MS decided to rename .NET Core, and furthermore why MS decided to rename .NET Core to something easily confused with .NET Framework is beyond me. The `PriorityQueue` class in the reference source is also quite a bit different from the .NET 6 `PriorityQueue`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using .Net 6 and up you can use Comparer with PriorityQueue as:

For Increasing order:

```
PriorityQueue<int,int> pq = new PriorityQueue<int,int>(Comparer<int>.Create((a,b)=>a-b));
```

or for decreasing order:

```
PriorityQueue<int,int> pq = new PriorityQueue<int,int>(Comparer<int>.Create((a,b)=>b-a));
```